# size of group points and parameters in pairing based cryptography

Tags: pairings

$$e:G_1\times G_1\rightarrow G_2$$
In symmetric pairing-based cryptography with groups$(G_1,G_2)$ of prime order $q$ and   $a,b \in Z_q$
Will the size of random generator $P$ from$ G_1$ and $a$ be same? I think it is different. I don't know why.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @fkraiem.$a,b$ selected from $Z_q$

Comment: Yes, I can see that much, but what are they for?

Comment: @fkraiem. They are for pairing-based cryptography.